# Redis will not start via bitbar / brew services start

Tags: homebrew, launchctl, redis

Trying to get redis managed via bitbar's brew services plugin, I cannot; it silently fails, and running `brew services start redis` also silently fails. Equally, `brew services list` shows it as started, but with an error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like homebrew has not been updating my configuration, so it was more than a major version out of date. Launchctl, and therefore brew services, always starts redis with the config file. I replace the config file with an updated one (from [the redis website](https://redis.io/topics/config)), and now my redis is being managed by brew services beautifully.